# Woocommerce - Admin Order Detail Page

Tags: woocommerce, admin, orders

I add one product for e.g “ABC” – price : $10 (including VAT 20%)

So product net price = £8 and tax = £2

In frontend on product detail page i show product price including TAX.($10)

When Customer purchase this product then in woocommerce order generate like this

```
product price = $8
tax = $2
-------------------
Total = $10

But i want price in admin order detail page like

product price : $10(including 20% VAT)
```

Not want to show VAT separate.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try this. Put it in your theme function.php file

```
     //Add price inc VAT column on admin order page
function action_woocommerce_admin_order_item_values( $null, $item, $absint ) {
    $val = ($item['type'] == 'line_item' || $item['type'] == 'shipping') ? $item['total'] + $item['total_tax'] : '&nbsp;';
    $valdecimal = wc_format_decimal( $val, $dp='', $trim_zeros );
    ?>
    <td class="item_fcost" data-sort-value="<?php echo $val; ?>">
        <div class="view" style="font-weight: bold; text-align: right; padding-right: 10px;">
            <?php if ($val>0) echo '$'; echo $valdecimal;?>
        </div>
    </td>
    <?php
};
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_item_values', 'action_woocommerce_admin_order_item_values', 10, 3 );


function action_woocommerce_admin_order_item_headers( $order ) {
    echo '<th class="item_fcost sortable" data-sort="float" style="text-align: right;">Price inc VAT</th>';
};
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_item_headers', 'action_woocommerce_admin_order_item_headers', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Perfect answer. Is there a way to also remove the default woocommerce columns, Cost, qty, total, tax?

Answer (score 0):

I updated the code above slightly, so it also works with fees and negative amounts:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_item_values', 'action_woocommerce_admin_order_item_values', 10, 3 );
  function action_woocommerce_admin_order_item_values( $null, $item, $item_id ) {
    $validOrderItemTypes = ['line_item', 'shipping', 'fee'];
    $val = ( in_array( $item['type'], $validOrderItemTypes )) ? $item['total'] + $item['total_tax'] : '&minus;';
    $price = wc_price( $val );
    ?>
    <td class="item_fcost" data-sort-value="<?php echo $val; ?>">
        <div class="view" style="font-weight: bold; text-align: right; padding-right: 10px;">
            <?php echo $price; ?>
        </div>
    </td>
    <?php
};

add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_item_headers', 'action_woocommerce_admin_order_item_headers', 10, 3 );
function action_woocommerce_admin_order_item_headers( $order ) {
    echo '<th class="item_fcost sortable" data-sort="float" style="text-align: right;">Price incl. VAT</th>';
};
```