# How to ignore a custom field in the order refund process in woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce, price

I use this code below in the my functions.php file.

```
 //Add price inc VAT column on admin order page
function action_woocommerce_admin_order_item_values( $null, $item, $absint ) {
    $val = ($item['type'] == 'line_item' || $item['type'] == 'shipping') ? $item['total'] + $item['total_tax'] : '&nbsp;';
    $valdecimal = wc_format_decimal( $val, $dp='', $trim_zeros );
    ?>
    <td class="item_fcost" data-sort-value="<?php echo $val; ?>">
        <div class="view" style="font-weight: bold; text-align: right; padding-right: 10px;">
            <?php if ($val>0) echo '$'; echo $valdecimal;?>
        </div>
    </td>
    <?php
};
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_item_values', 'action_woocommerce_admin_order_item_values', 10, 3 );


function action_woocommerce_admin_order_item_headers( $order ) {
    echo '<th class="item_fcost sortable" data-sort="float" style="text-align: right;">Price inc VAT</th>';
};
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_item_headers', 'action_woocommerce_admin_order_item_headers', 10, 3 );
```

This give me the opportunity to show show VAT $ separate.

You can learn more about this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46546482/woocommerce-admin-order-detail-page#new-answer)

The issue is that when I refund a product, I get the new woocommerce error (since 5.2)

The site is experiencing technical difficulties. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions.

I just look at the error and it seems that wocommerce display it because it can't find that custom field in the refund process...

```
 #3 /nas/content/staging/.../wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/admin/meta-boxes/views/html-order-refund.php(48): do_action('woocommerce_adm...', NULL, Object(WC_Order_Refund), 68711)
```

How can I remove this custom functions from the refund process? Is there a way to just hide this error?

Answer (score 0):

I hit this issue as well. The problem is that *woocommerce_admin_order_item_values* is now getting called with both [WC_Order_Refund](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order_Refund.html) as well as [WC_Order_item](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order_Item.html). We now have to discern which type of object we're getting when we receive it and handle accordingly. You can discern with this code.

```
if ($item->get_type() == 'shop_order_refund') {
    $item = new WC_Order_Refund($item_id);
}
else {
    $item = new WC_Order_Item_Product($item_id);
}
```

In your case I believe you need to change that first condition statement at the beginning of your code to something similar to.

```
switch ($item->get_type()) {
    case 'shop_order_refund':
        $val = $item->get_amount();
        break;
    case 'line_item':
    case 'shipping':
        $val = $item['total'] + $item['total_tax'];
        break;
    default:
        $val = '&nbsp;';
        break;
}
```