# Woocommerce - Display full price (incl. tax) in admin order summary

Tags: woocommerce, admin, orders

I wish to display the full price that the customer paid for the item, rather than 'price without tax' and 'tax'.

I followed this: [Woocommerce - Admin Order Detail Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46546482/woocommerce-admin-order-detail-page) and it almost gets me what I want, however it is not perfect to my case and I am failing to modify it. I am not very experienced in PHP and worried about breaking anything as it is a live webshop.

I managed to change the currency sign easily enough and put it at the end of the price rather than the start, but there's a couple of other things I wish to change and I'm not sure how/where.

1. We use commas instead of periods as decimal points. This is reflected without a problem everywhere else, but not with this custom snippet. How do I change this?
2. In the case of free item/shipping, this is empty. I tried to change "if $val>0" to just "if $val" but it made no difference.
3. I'd like this entire column to be on the right (as the last column) rather than on the left. So it reads Quantity, Total, Tax, Total incl. Tax.

Here is my current, slightly modified code:

```
function action_woocommerce_admin_order_item_values( $null, $item, $absint ) {
    $val = ($item['type'] == 'line_item' || $item['type'] == 'shipping') ? $item['total'] + $item['total_tax'] : '&nbsp;';
    $valdecimal = wc_format_decimal( $val, $dp='', $trim_zeros );
    ?>
    <td class="item_fcost" data-sort-value="<?php echo $val; ?>">
        <div class="view" style="font-weight: bold; text-align: right; padding-right: 10px;">
            <?php if ($val) echo $valdecimal; echo ' DKK'; ?>
        </div>
    </td>
    <?php
};
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_item_values', 'action_woocommerce_admin_order_item_values', 10, 3 );


function action_woocommerce_admin_order_item_headers( $order ) {
    echo '<th class="item_fcost sortable" data-sort="float" style="text-align: right;">Pris inkl. moms</th>';
};
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_item_headers', 'action_woocommerce_admin_order_item_headers', 10, 3 );
```

Edit: I found out that this code also breaks/throws a fatal error with refunded orders. I've had to deactivate the code entirely.

I'm not experienced enough to know how to modify it and am still looking for help.

Answer (score 0):

There was a little problem in your code and that's that you were accesing the `$item` as it was an array while it's actually an object. One of the objects extending the [`WC_Order_Item`](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Order-Item.html) abstract classes. Also, the `total` and `total_tax` properties of `$item` are strings, not numbers so when you are adding them together, you first need to convert them to floats.

Lastly, I reasearched [how the total is displayed by Woocommerce](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/trunk/includes/admin/meta-boxes/views/html-order-item.php) and they include the refunded total too. So I added the refunded total including VAT/tax too.

You can find updated code below.

```
function action_woocommerce_admin_order_item_values( $null, WC_Order_Item $item) {
    $val = floatval($item->get_total()) + floatval($item->get_total_tax());
    ?>
    <td class="item_full_cost" data-sort-value="<?= $val ?>">
        <div class="view" style="font-weight: bold; text-align: right; padding-right: 10px;">
            <?= wc_price($val, ['currency' => $item->get_order()->get_currency()]) ?>
        </div>
        <?php
        $refunded = $item->get_order()->get_total_refunded_for_item( $item->get_id() );

        if ( $refunded ) {
            echo '<small class="refunded">-' . wc_price( $refunded, array( 'currency' => $item->get_order()->get_currency() ) ) . '</small>';
        }
        ?>
    </td>
    <?php
};
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_item_values', 'action_woocommerce_admin_order_item_values', 10, 2 );


function action_woocommerce_admin_order_item_headers( $order ) {
    echo '<th class="line_full_cost sortable" data-sort="float" style="font-weight:bold;text-align: right;">' . __('Price incl. VAT') .'</th>';
};
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_item_headers', 'action_woocommerce_admin_order_item_headers', 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry that this is a little late to the party. The answer provided by Honza Kopecky is right with regard to how you need to treat the `$item` variable as an object instead of an array.

However you may still experience issues when trying to action refunds because the `woocommerce_admin_order_item_values` hook fires both on order item changes and on refunds and refunds are *not exactly* orders and the `$item` that gets passed to your hook in this case is *not exactly* an instance of the `WC_Order_Item` class either and this triggers the error message. You can get around this by removing the strongly typed class name in the function declaration:

`function action_woocommerce_admin_order_item_values( $null, $item)`

and surrounding the whole block in an `if` condition check such as

`if ( 'line_item' == $item->get_type() ) { /* rest of code */ }}`

to ensure you're dealing with order line items so that methods like `$item->get_order()->get_currency()` will not throw an error like **Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_currency() on bool**.

So the revised code could look something like this:

```php
function action_woocommerce_admin_order_item_values( $null, $item ) {
  $val = floatval($item->get_total()) + floatval($item->get_total_tax());
  if ( 'line_item' == $item->get_type() ) {
  ?>
  <td class="item_full_cost" data-sort-value="<?= $val ?>">
  ...
  </td>
  <?php
  }
};
```

Alternatively...you could also just install the plugin my team built (https://wordpress.org/plugins/rd-wc-order-modifier/) that adds this feature to the order screen because we struggled with the very same issue!