# How to display full price (including tax) in Admin Order Detail Page in Woocommerce?

Tags: php, woocommerce, admin

In Woocommerce, in the Admin Order Detail Page, I wish to display the full price (including taxes) that the customer paid for each item line, in addition to the 'price without tax' and 'tax'.
Surprisingly, it is not a core option of woo-commerce.
So far, I have followed [Woocommerce - Display full price (incl. tax) in admin order summary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68818687/woocommerce-display-full-price-incl-tax-in-admin-order-summary) and [Woocommerce - Admin Order Detail Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46546482/woocommerce-admin-order-detail-page).
I have tried the two different code snippets (thanks to the guy who shared it), and it is **working well for adding a column with the price including taxes for ALMOST all situations**.

Except for **, it is causing fatal error/breaks with refunded orders** which is not good for a business website as you can imagine.

Could you help me? I am quite new and learning PHP, so I am not an expert and I can't find what goes wrong in the code.

Right now I am using the code provided by Honza Kopecky (thank you!) in https://stackoverflow.com/a/69532601/17338625 :

```
function action_woocommerce_admin_order_item_values( $null, WC_Order_Item $item) {
$val = floatval($item->get_total()) + floatval($item->get_total_tax());
?>
<td class="item_full_cost" data-sort-value="<?= $val ?>">
    <div class="view" style="font-weight: bold; text-align: right; padding-right: 10px;">
        <?= wc_price($val, ['currency' => $item->get_order()->get_currency()]) ?>
    </div>
    <?php
    $refunded = $item->get_order()->get_total_refunded_for_item( $item->get_id() );

    if ( $refunded ) {
        echo '<small class="refunded">-' . wc_price( $refunded, array( 'currency' => $item->get_order()->get_currency() ) ) . '</small>';
    }
    ?>
</td>
<?php
};
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_item_values', 'action_woocommerce_admin_order_item_values', 10, 2 );


function action_woocommerce_admin_order_item_headers( $order ) {
    echo '<th class="line_full_cost sortable" data-sort="float" style="font-weight:bold;text-align: right;">' . __('Price incl. VAT') .'</th>';
};
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_item_headers', 'action_woocommerce_admin_order_item_headers', 10, 3 );
```

I suppose that for refunded orders, some functions are different or some amounts are negative, maybe that's why this code snippet is causing a fatal error?
Maybe it will be easier to add a condition in the code, not to show price including taxes when the order is refunded? But I don't know how to do...

Thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer provided by Honza Kopecky that you referenced should definitely get you close to what you need.

You are right that the system behaves differently when trying to action refunds and triggers an error, it is not so much because of the negative values but rather that the `woocommerce_admin_order_item_values` hook fires both on order item changes and on refunds and refunds are *not exactly* orders as far as WooCommerce is concerned and the `$item` that gets passed to your hook in this case is *not exactly* an instance of the `WC_Order_Item` class either and this triggers the error message. You can get around this by removing the strongly typed class name in the function declaration:

`function action_woocommerce_admin_order_item_values( $null, $item)`

You are also correct that an `if` condition check is needed to handle the different behaviour, and it would probably look something like this:

`if ( 'line_item' == $item->get_type() ) { /* rest of code */ }}`

which is a check to ensure you are dealing with order line items so that methods like `$item->get_order()->get_currency()` will not throw an error like **Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_currency() on bool**.

So the revised code could look something like this:

```php
function action_woocommerce_admin_order_item_values( $null, $item ) {
  $val = floatval($item->get_total()) + floatval($item->get_total_tax());
  if ( 'line_item' == $item->get_type() ) {
  ?>
  <td class="item_full_cost" data-sort-value="<?= $val ?>">
  ...
  </td>
  <?php
  }
};
```

Alternatively...you could also just install the plugin my team built (https://wordpress.org/plugins/rd-wc-order-modifier/) that adds this feature to the order screen because we struggled with the very same issue!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Indeed, I have tried your plugin and it has solved my problem :) Very good work on that !

Answer (score 0):

Just found a couple of hooks that might help you with that.

First we add an extra table header using the hook that woo provides in **html-order-items.php**

```
 add_action('woocommerce_admin_order_item_headers', 'order_header',10,1);

function order_header($order){
    ?>
        <th class="total_with_vat sortable" colspan="2" data-sort="float"><?php esc_html_e( 'Total + Vat', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
    <?php
}
```

Then add extra table field with **woocommerce_admin_order_item_values** and get the product price. I make a couple of checks. First you should check if current object is a product because in order-items there are not only product but also ,shipping – shipping type, fee – fee type [rudrastyh make a greak explanation here](https://rudrastyh.com/woocommerce/order-items.html)

And second check is when I show the total price I check if the product $item['total'] is equal to 0 cause it might is a gift or free of charge so there is no need to display the price.

```
    add_action('woocommerce_admin_order_item_values', 'show_total', 10, 3);

function show_total( $product, $item, $item_id ){
    if (!is_a($product, 'WC_Product')){
        return;
    }
?>
        <td class="item_total_cost" colspan="2" width="1%">
        <div class="view">
            <?php
            echo ($item['total'] >  0) ? $product->get_price() . get_woocommerce_currency_symbol() : $item['total'] . get_woocommerce_currency_symbol() ;
            ?>
        </div>
    </td>
<?php
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and sorry for my late answer. I tried to use this code but it was above my level so I was unable to make the whole thing work. I finally found the plugin mentioned by camper2020 that solved the problem several month later. Have a nice day !